# Error Paypal: las cantidades de los detalles de la transacción deben sumar el total

Tags: paypal

La API de PayPal me devuelve el siguiente error en el paypal_log y no sé muy bien cuál es el error o cómo solucionarlo:

```
INFO: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
INFO: Response Status   : 200
INFO: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
INFO: Response Status   : 400
ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment. {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount total"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"ac3fb5c4789f0"}
```

Comment: El error dice que las cantidades no coinciden. ¿Seguro que no estás haciendo algún cálculo mal en algún sitio?

Comment: Si, si, me di cuenta de ello, la cuestión, es que poniendo 100 como precio de envio para que me lo gestione me lo hace correctamente, sin embargo, yo quisiera poner el precio que yo quisiera